# How can I manually create a sources jar file to deploy to Nexus or use in Intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea, jar, nexus

I have here an outdated source code built with ant. But it's stil used as a library though.
For reference reason I want to able to have a look in the sources.

How can I manually create a sources jar file so that it's recognized by Intellij and Nexus as source to an already existing library?

So I can browse the referenced libraries sources for debugging reason for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Package the source code in a zip (in the same directory structure usually used in sources jars), and upload it in Nexus through artifact upload, giving it the classifier "sources". This should to the trick.

Comment: I also added the same meta inf. Yet I dunno if it's necessary.

I had issues with my Linux zip application, which produced a corrupt zip file when I tried to create a "jar" file in it.
2nd try worked by just creating a zip file and then renaming it.